# plpgsql function adding key-value to JSONB

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

What plpgsql function would you write to add a key value element to a JSONB column ?

```
+--------+---------------+-------------------+
| id[PK] | name(varchar) |   value(JSONB)    |
+--------+---------------+-------------------+
|      1 | test          | {"key1":"value1"} |
+--------+---------------+-------------------+
```

I use this SQL query to add a new element to the JSONB :

```
UPDATE output_controlling_variables SET value = value || '{"key1" : "value1"}' WHERE id = 1
```

What would be a plpgsql function to do this by taking key(str) and value(str) as arguments ?
I am trying with this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_id(test_id varchar,test_name varchar)
BEGIN
    --RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
    QUERY EXECUTE
    format('UPDATE output_controlling_variables SET value = value || %s WHERE id = 4')
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Should I format the `'{"key1" : "value1"}'` part ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jsonb_build_object()` to build a JSON from the parameters and append it to the value in the column. Also there's no need for dynamic SQL here just directly use an `UPDATE` statement.

```
...
UPDATE output_controlling_variables
       SET value = value || jsonb_build_object(test_id, test_name)
       WHERE id = 4;
...
```